# How do I format this text? java

Tags: java

So here's the problem. Turn a text file into the correct formatting. 
The point of the problem is that I have to read a file, a text file, which contains code in that text file. The code in that has terrible formatting. The formatting issue is that when there is a curly brace like this `{`, the next line is not 4 spaces to the right, it's just all to the very left. Like this:

```
while (blah blah blah) { 
sysout(blahblahblah);
```

When it should be this:

```
while (blah blah blah) { 
    sysout(blahblahblah);
```

And there's no other differences between the 2. The only rule is to simply make it so every time there is a curly brace like this {, to make sure the next line is 4 spaces to the right. And vice versa. So every time there's a curly brace like this }, the next line should be 4 spaces to the left. I hope you guys understand this.

This is my issue. I learned how to make a program where a piece of text with multiple spaces and lines is turned into a single line with a single space every time. Wasn't too hard.

For this, though, I have to keep everything on the same line. So if there's 30 lines, the new program I make is also 30 lines. I need to keep very similar spacing, but the simple difference is the whole brace thing. So basically, I just have to make the line after a brace either 4 spaces to the right, and then do the same so it is to the left 4 spaces if it's a `}` curly brace.

So how do I do this exactly? I don't know how to just fix that without messing up other things. It's such a simple thing I have to do; just make the lines following the braces 4 spaces to the right or left, but I just have no idea what syntax to use to accomplish this. Thanks!

EDIT: This might have just made it easier. So, basically, all lines either end with a right curly brace, a left curly brace, or a semi-colon. No matter what. So every time one of those pops up, it is the end of a line. So maybe if you know how that makes it easier, then I'm just letting you know.

Answer (score 0):

There are programs that will do this for you automatically, so you don't need to reinvent the wheel. For instance, in Eclipse, type: `ctrl-a` (select all) `ctrl-i` (auto-indent).

Comment: This is for a school assignment. My teacher will input a text file containing a big chunk of code. My output must contain a modified version, with correct spacing.

Comment: Ah, so you are asking us to do your homework for you.

Comment: I spent hours thinking about how to do this. I have come up with nothing. I just want some pointers. I don't have much vocabulary and I am unable to do this. There's no machine that can help me with this. I never asked for someone to write this out. But how to simply manipulate a text file so that after curly braces, the next line is 4 spaces to the right, or to the left. I don't have a lot of vocabulary, and that might be what is killing me. But why leave someone in the dust all because they can't do something. I already stated that this is not a plot to get someone to do my hw for me

Comment: Perhaps you could ask a more specific question without using vocabulary, then. Do you need to learn how to read a file? Do you need to learn how to add spaces to a line? Do you need to learn how to keep track of the number of spaces? Any of these would help someone answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pseudocode you can start with:

```
int indentLevel = 0;
while(currentchar = nextchar != null){
    printCurrentChar
    if(currentchar is '{'){
        indentLevel++;
    }else if(currentchar is '}'){
        indentLevel--;
    }else if(currentchar is '\n'){
        print indentLevel * 4 spaces
    }
}
```

you might need to deal with escaped braces and other complications though

Answer (score 0):

You can do this pretty easily using regular expressions. If you do not know it and planning to be a programmer, then definitely learn it. It will save for you lots of time in future.

```
public class TextIndentator
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        File uglyText = new File("ugly.txt");
        System.out.println((uglyText.exists() && !uglyText.isDirectory()) ? getNiceText(uglyText) : "FILE \"ugly.txt\" at " + System.getProperty("user.dir") + " do not exists");
    }

    static String getNiceText(File uglyText) throws IOException
    {
        // Opening file
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(uglyText);
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

        // Algorithm starts here
        String line;
        boolean checkNext = false;
        while ((line  = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            if(checkNext)
            {
                // If previous line finished with '{' (And optionally with some whitespaces after it) then, replace any amount (including zero) of whitespaces with 4 witespaces
                builder.append(line.replaceFirst("\\s*", "    "));
            }
            else
            {
                builder.append(line);
            }
            // Check if line line finishes with { (And optionally with some whitespaces after it)
            if(line.matches(".*\\{\\s*")) checkNext = true;
            else checkNext = false;

            //Append line separator at the end of line
            builder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }

}
```